# Create multiple GUIs

Tags: user-interface, autoit

We've got an AutoIt script to streamline our processes. The original version has been handed around and all were afraid to delete things, so I'm to rewrite it from scratch. The idea is to be a 'control panel' to launch some tasks. I'm trying to make it smaller and more streamlined so our on-the-floor techs can use it from tablets.

I'd like to create buttons that launch separate windows with the information the tech needs. The problem is trying to close the new windows when generated. I've got the second GUI to open, I just can't close it.

I tried variations of `WinClose("title")` and `WinKill("title")`, but neither work. They always end up locking the entire script. I'm using messageloop format, but I'm open to suggestions. My code:

```
#include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>
#include <ButtonConstants.au3>
#include <EditConstants.au3>
#include <StaticConstants.au3>
#include <windowsConstants.au3>
#include <ColorConstants.au3>

;Button Declarations
Global $List

;GUI Creation
Opt('MustDeclarVars', 1) ;Creates an error message if a variable is used by not declared.
GUICreate("Tech Control Panel", 450, 530) ;Creates the GUI and it's elements.
GUISetState(@SW_SHOW)

;Button creation and location settings
;Left Column
GUICtrlCreateLabel("Tools", 10, 10, 100, 30, $SS_CENTER)
$List = GUICtrlCreateButton("Tech List", 10, 30, 100, 30)

;Main loop, gets GUI actions and processes them
While 1
    $msg = GUIGetMsg()
    Select
        Case $msg = $TechList
            GUICreate("List", 200, 300)
            GUISetState(@SW_SHOW)
            While 1
                $msg = GUIGetMsg()
                Select
                    Case $msg = $GUI_Event_Close
                        WinClose("List")
                EndSelect
            WEnd
        Case $msg = $GUI_Event_Close
            Exit
    EndSelect
WEnd
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the advanced version of [`GUIGetMsg`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/GUIGetMsg.htm) in order to identify the window that has send the event. To do this you have to store the handle when you create the windows like this:

```
$hGuiMain = GUICreate(...)
$hGuiHelp = GUICreate(...) 
$hGuiAbout = GUICreate(...)
```

Inside your main loop you are now able to test which window has send the event. If you know which window was triggered you can close the window or do whatever you want to do.

```
While 1
    $aMsg = GUIGetMsg(1)
    Switch $aMsg[1]
        Case $hGuiMain
            If $aMsg[0] = $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE Or $aMsg[0] = $mnuFileExit Then
                ExitLoop
            EndIf
        Case $hGuiHelp
            If $aMsg[0] = $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE Then
                GUISetState(@SW_ENABLE, $hGuiMain)
                GUIDelete($hGuiHelp)
            EndIf
        Case $hGuiAbout
            If $aMsg[0] = $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE Then
                GUISetState(@SW_ENABLE, $hGuiMain)
                GUIDelete($hGuiAbout)
            EndIf
    EndSwitch
WEnd
```